# How to perform a join containing a sub query on an Eloquent Relationship in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am new to laravel. I'm working on this laravel 5 app but got stuck on trying to perform a query like below.

```
select * from carts inner join users on carts.manager_id = users.id
where cart_num like "e%" OR name like "e%"
having region = (select region from users where id = 3);
```

**Edit**

The aim of the query is to get the carts of managers in the same region as an administrator (hence reason for the subselect. id is the id of the administrator)

**Edit**

I have come out with something like so:

```
return Cart::join('users', 'carts.manager_id', '=', 'users.id')
             ->where('cart_num', 'like', $match . '%')
             ->orWhere('name', 'like', $match . '%')
             ->having('region', '=', function ($query) use ($id) {
                 return $query->select('region')->where('id', '=', $id);
            })
            ->get();
```

Any idea on how I can polish the having clause. I get the error Object of class Closure could not be converted to string. Thanks

Comment: add ->get(); at the end of the enclosed query
               .  return $query->select('region')->where('id', '=', $id)->get();

Comment: I have added ->get() but get the same error. Any idea on what I am missing.

Comment: 'subject' => 'select * from `carts` inner join `users` on `carts`.`manager_id` = `users`.`id` where `cart_num` like a% or `name` like a% having `region` = ?', 'value' => object(Closure)))

Comment: Yes it should be ... ->get()->region;
But check my edited answer for a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need here

```
return Cart::join('users','carts.manager_id','=','users.id')
            ->where('cart_num', 'like', $match)
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', $match."%")
            ->having('region','=', $region)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @Dimitris. Your answer is close but the structure of my relations is a problem. Cart is related to Manager and Manager is  a Sub class of User. Please check the question update if you can help out.

Comment: Manager has an 1 to 1 relationship with user?

Comment: Yes @Dimitris. Is a 1 to 1

Comment: Thank you so much @Dimitiris. I couldn't have gone this far without your help. The edit works beautifully for my need.

Answer (score 0):

This is an identical query without that subselect, which I dont think is necessary. Could you implement this instead and pass the region parameter to it? Your user already has a region since you joined on that table, and `user.id` *should* be the primary key, so you're going to have one region anyway.

```
select * from carts inner join users 
on carts.manager_id = users.id
and users.region = $region
where cart_num like "e%" OR name like "e%" ;
```

Comment: The aim of the query is to get the carts of managers in the same region as an administrator (hence reason for the subselect. id is the id of the administrator). I think the query is pretty ok.